# How to modify the input appearance on command window

Tags: c

I feel quite 'stupid' as asking this question but if anyone can show me the methods to modify the input result appeared on the command window.

Example:

I want to sort 5 numbers (1, 3, 4, 7, 5) in smallest-to-biggest order and the result on the command window must be:

```
input: 1 3 4 7 5 /* 1 line input */
output: 1 3 4 5 7 /* 1 line output */
```

Edit:
Here is my code

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    scanf("%d ", &array[i]);
}
```

If I use this code the result on command window must be:

```
1
3
4
7
5
```

But I want all the input number in only 1 line as:

```
1 3 4 7 5
```

So what do I have to do with my code?

Comment: Please choose a language — C or C++, but not both.  They are different, and the appropriate answers will be radically different.  Since you mention you're new to C, I will assume that you need the C tag and not the C++ tag.  (Note that the first comment used the C++ tag to give you a workable (albeit unnecessarily verbose) answer.)

Comment: Thanks for ur response buti'm programming by using c language so no "cin" and "cout". And let me explain more. I know my question is quite ambiguous.

Comment: change to `scanf("%d", &array[i]);` You can be entered on a single line without change.

Comment: If you want the input on a single line, simply type them on a single line.  `scanf()` doesn't require newlines between numbers.  Also, eliminate the trailing blank from the `"%d "` format string; it doesn't mean what you think it does.  In fact, it means read input after the first number until the user types something that isn't white space (blank, tab, newline, etc).  It is a diabolical thing to use in an interactive program.  The `"%d" format skips leading white space without any extra help from you (only `%c` and `%[…]` — and `%n` — do not skip white space).

Comment: Thank you. I made it. Is there anything like "thank-button" in this forum? :D

Comment: Got it. Thanks for ur help.
Last time to say thank. I've just read the About page. LOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to your edited question, just replace `"%d "` with `"%d"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

int main(void){
    int i, j, array[N];

    printf("Please enter the %d numbers.\n", N);
    printf("input : ");
    for(i=0;i<N;++i){
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        if(i!=0){
            for(j=i;j>0 && array[j-1] > array[j];--j){
                //swap array[j] and array[j-1]
                int tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j-1];
                array[j-1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("output : ");
    for(i=0;i<N;++i){
        if(i!=0)
            putchar(' ');
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```